# node.js variable scope after module export

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, export

I would have to access a variable outside of my module, even if the variable reference is updated.

Bellow my module.js:

```
'use strict';

const Foo = () => {
    const _date = new Date();
    const _id = _date.getTime().toString(16);
    console.log(`Foo() _id: ${_id}`);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
        f = Foo();
    }, 5000); // 5s
    
    return {
        get_id: () => {
            return _id;
        }
    }
}

let f = Foo();

module.exports = {
    foo: f,
}
```

Bellow my index.js:

```
const {foo} = require('./module');

console.log(`foo.get_id(): ${foo.get_id()}`);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`foo.get_id(): ${foo.get_id()}`);
}, 3000); // 3s
```

It's ouput:

> $ node index.js
>
> Foo() _id: 17b0babddc1
>
> foo.get_id(): 17b0babddc1
>
> foo.get_id(): 17b0babddc1
>
> Foo() _id: 17b0babf15e
>
> Foo() _id: 17b0bac04f5

foo.get_id() seem to be undefined after I update the variable f on the module.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your Foo function is waiting 5 seconds then attempting to assign `f = Foo();` but variable `f` is not accessible from your function.

Answer (score 0):

However `f` is global, I don't understand.